# Calling another method to get resultset and closing the connection correctly?

Tags: java, jdbc, try-catch

```
try{
      String query= "select user_name from user";
      ResultSet rs = queries.performQuery(query);

while(rs.next()){
        System.out.println("User Name :" + rs.getString("user_name"));
      }
```

in another class I have something like this:

```
public ResultSet performQuery(String query) throws SQLException
    {       
        try 
        {
              connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sqlUrl,sqlUser,sqlPassword);
              stmt = connection.createStatement();
                  rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        } 

        catch(SQLException ex) 
        {
        }

        finally{
            close(rs);
            close(stmt);
            close(connection);
        }
        return rs;
    }
```

Now I get the error Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed, and it's obviously because I'm closing the rs/stmt/connection.

I don't have my code with me so this is just off the top of my head, disregard any syntax errors and I hope my question is still clear enough.

So my question is this:

If you want to have a method that for example performs queries, and you call that in another method and then do rs.next, what is the appropriate way to close the resultset/stmt/connection? To me it makes sense to close them the performQuery, but that gives me the error.

Comment: Well, you perform a query and close the `ResultSet`, but actually *retrieving* the result rows needs an open `ResultSet`. So your only option is to leave the `ResultSet` open after performing the query, so you can retrieve the results... After that, close it. It's probably better to create 1 method that both performs the query AND retrieves the results (if that's what you're after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using `ResultSet` then it will need the Connection to load more rows . for example if your query returns 1000 record , first the ResultSet will hold 41 row in memory then when you iterate over this number it will use the Connection to load another chuck of records .in your case i would use `RowSet` [for more explanation read this](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/591)

Comment: Thanks, so how would you suggest closing the connections? Only close in the method calling the rs.next? but then I can't close connection and stmt since it only contains a reference to rs?

Comment: you can return an ArrayList instead of ResultSet , inside your method iterate over the ResultSet and fill the ArrayList with records then when you finish looping the ResultSet return the ArrayList

Answer (score 1):

`ResultSet` is designed to allow streaming of results, e.g. one record at a time. That's why it is not simply returning a `Collection` of some kind but rather something similar to iterator. In fact `ResultSet` can lazily load one record at a time through open JDBC connection.

That being said if you are comfortable with having all the results in memory at the same time - just eagerly load all records before closing `ResultSet`.